# Can EU nationals enter and exit Albania with EU ID card?

Tags: eu, albania

I was wondering if I need a passport or I can simply use my EU ID card to enter and exit Albania?

Many thanks,

KG

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use your ID card instead of your passport.  The [November 2018 list (pdf)](http://punetejashtme.gov.al/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/3-visa-regime-for-foreign-citiznes-01.11.2018.pdf) shows that all European Union countries are among those whose citizens are permitted to enter Albania with a national ID card.

It should be noted that "national ID card" generally means an identification card issued by a national government that identifies the holder as a national of that country.  In particular, a driver's license does not suffice.