# Entering Greece with EU ID card by land

Tags: eu, greece, eu-id-card

As an EU citizen, can I enter Greece with only an ID card instead of a passport coming from outside EU (North Macedonia or Albania) by car?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Well I rarely travel, and when I do I've always used a passport. But the ID card alternative seems way more convenient, and I've just recently overheard it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use either an EU ID card or Passport to enter the EU (Proof of EU citizenship).

> According to the Migration and Social Inclusion Code (Article 4(6) of Law 4251/2014), entry to Greece may not be refused to persons who are proved to be Greek nationals or nationals of an EU member state, even if not in possession of a passport or other travel documents.

Source: https://www.gov.gr/en/sdg/travel-within-eu/travel-documents/expired-lost-stolen-passports-identity-cards

However, Albanian or North Macedonian authorities might need a passport for exit checks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

To build on meego's answer, yes, you may enter Greece with an ID card, and you may also enter (and therefore also leave) both [North Macedonia](https://www.mfa.gov.mk/en/page/432/visa-requirements-for-entering-the-republic-of-north-macedonia) and [Albania](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/128518/can-eu-nationals-enter-and-exit-albania-with-eu-id-card) with an ID card from the EU/EEA.

North Macedonia:

> Nationals of EU Member States and signatories of the Schengen Agreement DO NOT need a visa to enter the Republic of North Macedonia (and are eligible to enter the Republic of North Macedonia with a valid national identity card)

Anecdotally, this works fine for all of the non-EU countries on the Balkan peninsula (I've done this many times), although I don't have official sources for each country.